# How to pass variables into a model's __construct function when using Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass variables into the model when I call it from the controller...

$this->load->model('Some_model',$var1, $var2);

$var1 and $var2 being collected from the URL in the controller's index function. However these are not being picked up in the code?

Is this at all possible as it is pretty important that they are there from the get go in the model?

thanks.

Comment: You need to add them to the constructor as well. Have you?

Comment: `it is pretty important that they are there from the get go in the model?` Why's that, then?

Comment: The second parameter is used to rename the instance of the model. For example, $this->load->model("Some_model", "some_model_renamed"); $this->some_model_renamed->blah_blah();

Comment: I'm extending a library which requires certain things to happen in order to use it. If this model is to do what I want it to, then I need to supply some variables to tell it what to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't do that with the built-in loader, the model [loading code hardcoded](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L303) with empty `new` parameters (at least in version 2.1).

You might want to move your code to a library since library loading can take a second array parameter with options, [see here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html).

Since CI's loader will only create one instance of these classes, you can move your configuration into the config files and read them from there in your `__construct`.

Alternatively you could extend the `Loader` class and reimplement the `model()` method to take some parameters (if you don't mind having a 4th parameter or something like that).

Comment: I have figured it out by overriding the function in the library that I'm extending with another in the model I'm writing. That way I can do all the set up it needs far more dynamically. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Models don't take data arguments when loaded. Models reflect the underlying data model of your application. This should never change based on user input.

Here is [the documentation for loading models](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading) which I'm sure you have already read (hopefully you're not just *programming by guessing‽*); there is an optional second argument that allows you to override the model's name, but no facility for passing data.

Instead, consider using a *library*, or pass these arguments to whichever model functions need them.